# How to edit properties of a Custom Model in a list (Flutter/Dart)?

Tags: arrays, list, flutter, dart

I have this log food functionality in my flutter application. There are two ways to add food (1) is adding to the list which is fairly easy since all I have to do is listName.add(ModelName(properties: value); However, the (2) way is by editing indices of the initial list which is shown here:

```
import 'package:thesis/foodAPICalls/food.dart';

class MealsListData {
  int id;
  String imagePath;
  String titleTxt;
  String startColor;
  String endColor;
  DateTime date;
  Nutritionix nutritionix;
  String meals;
  double totalCalories;

  MealsListData({
    this.id,
    this.imagePath = '',
    this.titleTxt = '',
    this.startColor = "",
    this.endColor = "",
    this.date,
    this.nutritionix,
    this.meals,
    this.totalCalories = 0,
  });

  static List<MealsListData> mealEntry = [
     MealsListData(
      id: 1,
      imagePath: 'assets/fitness_app/breakfast.png',
      titleTxt: 'Breakfast',
      totalCalories:  0,
      meals: '',
      date: DateTime.now(),
      startColor: "#FA7D82",
      endColor: "#FFB295",
    ),
    MealsListData(
      id: 2,
      imagePath: 'assets/fitness_app/lunch.png',
      titleTxt: 'Lunch',
      totalCalories: 0,
      meals: '',
      date: DateTime.now(),
      startColor: "#738AE6",
      endColor: "#5C5EDD",
    ),
    MealsListData(
      id: 3,
      imagePath: 'assets/fitness_app/snack.png',
      titleTxt: 'Snack',
      totalCalories: 0,
      meals: 'Recommend: 800 kcal',
      startColor: "#FE95B6",
      endColor: "#FF5287",
    ),
    MealsListData(
      id: 4,
      imagePath: 'assets/fitness_app/dinner.png',
      titleTxt: 'Dinner',
      totalCalories: 0,
      meals: 'Recommend: 703 kcal',
      startColor: "#6F72CA",
      endColor: "#1E1466",
    ),

  ];
}
```

Here is what it looks like UI-Wise:

[image]

I've created a function in the UI which passed the ID of the list into my addFood() screen

```
onTap:(){
 Navigator.push( context,MaterialPageRoute
(builder: (context) => AddFood(id: mealsListData.id,)),);
},
```

And Inside the adding Food Screen I've created a lengthy nested if-else to check if the user is trying to add with way 1 or way 2

```
 void _submitData() {
  List<MealsListData> mealEntry = MealsListData.mealEntry;
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();
      double totalCalories = 0;
      print(nutritionix.food.length);
      for (int i = 0; i < nutritionix.food.length; i++) {
        totalCalories = nutritionix.food[i].calories + totalCalories;
      }
      print(totalCalories);

      if (idcount == null) { // WAY 1 (adding to initial List)
        switch (_foodTypeInput) {
          case 'Breakfast':
            {
              mealEntry.add(MealsListData(
                id: idcount++,
                imagePath: 'assets/fitness_app/breakfast.png',
                titleTxt: _foodTypeInput,
                totalCalories: totalCalories,
                meals: _food,
                date: _selectedDate,
                nutritionix: nutritionix,
                startColor: "#FA7D82",
                endColor: "#FFB295",
              ));
              Navigator.pop(context);
            }
            break;

          case 'Lunch':
            {
              mealEntry.add(MealsListData(
                id: idcount++,
                imagePath: 'assets/fitness_app/lunch.png',
                titleTxt: _foodTypeInput,
                totalCalories: 590,
                meals: _food,
                date: _selectedDate,
                nutritionix: nutritionix,
                startColor: "#738AE6",
                endColor: "#5C5EDD",
              ));
              Navigator.pop(context);
            }
            break;

          case 'Snack':
            {
              mealEntry.add(MealsListData(
                id: idcount++,
                imagePath: 'assets/fitness_app/snack.png',
                titleTxt: _foodTypeInput,
                totalCalories: 200,
                meals: _food,
                date: _selectedDate,
                nutritionix: nutritionix,
                startColor: "#FE95B6",
                endColor: "#FF5287",
              ));
              Navigator.pop(context);
            }
            break;

          case 'Dinner':
            {
              mealEntry.add(MealsListData(
                id: idcount++,
                imagePath: 'assets/fitness_app/dinner.png',
                titleTxt: _foodTypeInput,
                totalCalories: 600,
                meals: _food,
                date: _selectedDate,
                nutritionix: nutritionix,
                startColor: "#6F72CA",
                endColor: "#1E1466",
              ));
              Navigator.pop(context);
            }
            break;
        }
      } else{ // WAY 2 editing index based on id
        var newEntry = mealEntry.firstWhere((id) => id.id == idcount, orElse: null );
        if(newEntry!=null){
        newEntry.totalCalories = totalCalories;
        newEntry.meals= _food;
        newEntry.nutritionix= nutritionix;
        Navigator.pop(context);
        } else{}

      }

      print(mealEntry);
      print(_foodTypeInput);
      print(_food);
      print(_selectedDate);
    }
  }
```

For the Way 2: what I've done is created the firstWhere for my custom model, however I keep getting this error "Bad state: No element" How do I resolve this? Thank you for reading my lengthy post. I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Woops, turns out I wasn't using the data passed to the Widget. I was supposed to use widget.idcount not just idcount.